# What's the difference between these two and which should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the difference between these two and which should I use?

```
$.data(this, 'timer');
```

vs

```
$(this).data('timer');
```

Comment: The second is easier to read, IMO

Comment: @user1389596: I agree. Is there any difference in execution speed?

Comment: I'm not sure ... the biggest performance issue would be how many times is $(this) being instantiated in the code?   It's might be best to create one var, and reference it repeatedly if possible  Though not sure there is a performance difference without benchmarking (jquery tends to cache a lot regardless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no meaningful difference in result.  The difference is really just a matter of coding style.

The first is a more procedural approach where you call a globally namespaced function and pass it a couple arguments.

The second is more consistent with the object oriented style of jQuery where you create a jQuery object containing one or more DOM elements and then you call methods on it to affect those elements or get info from those elements.

---

If you were interested in the fine details of performance between the two methods, then you'd have to devise a performance test and measure in several browsers.  But, if you really wanted to optimize performance of a given operation, you would probably cut the jQuery out of the code completely since it is rarely the fastest way to do something.  It saves lots of coding time and offers great cross browser support (which both make it well worth it for most code), but often at the cost of some performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no diference, the second one is better to use but just for intellisense